# Crashed when set a “span” param to item in LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using a 'LazyVerticalGrid' with 2 cells to show list items  in a compose project. What I want is leting the last item occupy 2 cells, like this:

[enter image description here](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1))

My approach is set the last item's 'span' param to 'GridItemSpan(2)', but when items are not exceeding one page, it is normal.However, when the items exceeds one page, I slide the list, it will crash.

//My code:

```
    val list: List<Int> = ArrayList<Int>().apply {
        repeat(1000) {
            add(it)
        }
    }
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        state = state
    ) {
        items(list) {
            Text(text = "$it")
        }
        // both GridItemSpan(2) or GridItemSpan(1) here will crashed
        item(span = {
            GridItemSpan(2)
        }) {
            Text(text = "End")
        }
    }
```

// The Error Log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.getLineConfiguration(LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyMeasuredLineProvider.getAndMeasure-bKFJvoY(LazyMeasuredLineProvider.kt:60)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridMeasureKt.measureLazyGrid-0cYbdkg(LazyGridMeasure.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridKt$rememberLazyGridMeasurePolicy$1$1.measure-3p2s80s(LazyGrid.kt:324)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:68)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:514)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:54)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:306)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:40)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1918)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1289)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:246)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:693)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner$DefaultImpls.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:882)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23019)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21836)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21836)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4526)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4499)
```

// code where crashed:

```
// code in LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.kt file
fun getLineConfiguration(lineIndex: Int): LineConfiguration {
        if (!itemsProvider.hasCustomSpans) {
            // Quick return when all spans are 1x1 - in this case we can easily calculate positions.
            val firstItemIndex = lineIndex * slotsPerLine
            return LineConfiguration(
                firstItemIndex,
                getDefaultSpans(slotsPerLine.coerceAtMost(totalSize - firstItemIndex)
                    .coerceAtLeast(0))
            )
        }

        val bucket = lineIndex / bucketSize
        // We can calculate the items on the line from the closest cached bucket start item.
        var currentLine = min(bucket, bucketStartItemIndex.size - 1) * bucketSize
        var currentItemIndex = bucketStartItemIndex[min(bucket, bucketStartItemIndex.size - 1)]




        /** Here crashed!!!
        var knownCurrentItemSpan = bucketStartKnownSpan[min(bucket, bucketStartItemIndex.size - 1)]
        **/




        // ... but try using the more localised cached values.
        if (lastLineIndex in currentLine..lineIndex) {
            // The last calculated value is a better start point. Common when scrolling main axis.
            currentLine = lastLineIndex
            currentItemIndex = lastLineStartItemIndex
            knownCurrentItemSpan = lastLineStartKnownSpan
        } else if (bucket == cachedBucketIndex && lineIndex - currentLine < cachedBucket.size) {
            // It happens that the needed line start is fully cached. Common when scrolling in
            // reverse main axis, as we decided to cacheThisBucket previously.
            currentItemIndex = cachedBucket[lineIndex - currentLine]
            currentLine = lineIndex
            knownCurrentItemSpan = 0
        }

        val cacheThisBucket = currentLine % bucketSize == 0 &&
            lineIndex - currentLine in 2 until bucketSize
        if (cacheThisBucket) {
            cachedBucketIndex = bucket
            cachedBucket.clear()
        }

        check(currentLine <= lineIndex)

        while (currentLine < lineIndex && currentItemIndex < totalSize) {
            if (cacheThisBucket) {
                cachedBucket.add(currentItemIndex)
            }

            var spansUsed = 0
            while (spansUsed < slotsPerLine && currentItemIndex < totalSize) {
                val span = if (knownCurrentItemSpan == 0) {
                    spanOf(currentItemIndex, slotsPerLine - spansUsed)
                } else {
                    knownCurrentItemSpan.also { knownCurrentItemSpan = 0 }
                }
                if (spansUsed + span > slotsPerLine) {
                    knownCurrentItemSpan = span
                    break
                }

                currentItemIndex++
                spansUsed += span
            }
            ++currentLine
            if (currentLine % bucketSize == 0 && currentItemIndex < totalSize) {
                val currentLineBucket = currentLine / bucketSize
                // This should happen, as otherwise this should have been used as starting point.
                check(bucketStartItemIndex.size == currentLineBucket)
                bucketStartItemIndex.add(currentItemIndex)
                bucketStartKnownSpan.add(knownCurrentItemSpan)
            }
        }

        lastLineIndex = lineIndex
        lastLineStartItemIndex = currentItemIndex
        lastLineStartKnownSpan = knownCurrentItemSpan

        val firstItemIndex = currentItemIndex
        val spans = mutableListOf<GridItemSpan>()

        var spansUsed = 0
        while (spansUsed < slotsPerLine && currentItemIndex < totalSize) {
            val span = if (knownCurrentItemSpan == 0) {
                spanOf(currentItemIndex, slotsPerLine - spansUsed)
            } else {
                knownCurrentItemSpan.also { knownCurrentItemSpan = 0 }
            }
            if (spansUsed + span > slotsPerLine) break

            currentItemIndex++
            spans.add(GridItemSpan(span))
            spansUsed += span
        }
        return LineConfiguration(firstItemIndex, spans)
    }
```

Here is a copy of the official sample: [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1))

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.Text

val sections = (0 until 25).toList().chunked(5)
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(3),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
) {
    sections.forEachIndexed { index, items ->
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan) }) {
            Text(
                "This is section $index",
                Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Gray).height(80.dp).wrapContentSize()
            )
        }
        items(
            items,
            // not required as it is the default
            span = { GridItemSpan(1) }
        ) {
            Text(
                "Item $it",
                Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Blue).height(80.dp).wrapContentSize()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It work well, but when I increase the list "sections" ,

from:

```
val sections = (0 until 25).toList().chunked(5)
```

to:

```
val sections = (0 until 200).toList().chunked(5)
```

It crashed like my code.

Comment: doesn't crash to me, make sure you're using the latest Compose version, which is **1.1.1** ATM.

Comment: it crashes for me too, it's on latest alpha - `1.2.0-alpha04`

Comment: Star the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222551626) and wait Google to fix it.

Comment: Still crashing on 1.2.0-alpha06 :-(

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
item(
   span = {
     GridItemSpan(maxCurrentLineSpan)
   }
) {
    Text(text = "End")
  }
```

maxCurrentLineSpan would behave as a single column.